# Passing an @ObservableObject to a nested view

Tags: mvvm, swiftui, observedobject

I'm quite new to SwiftUI and trying to pass an array in a forEach-loop to another view, but Xcode says, that my 'Property type does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'ObservedObject'. I also found some similar questions here, but nothing of the solutions there helped me.

When I'm using the object directly in the forEach-loop everything is working as needed. However the view I want to implement inside the loop will be quite complex, so a solution to pass it to a new struct would be great.

I would be very thankful if someone could explain to me, why this code doesn't work and what I need to do to fix it.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Collectable: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let completion: Int
}

class AlbumViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var album: [Collectable] = [
        .init(id: 1, name: "Album 1", completion: Int.random(in: 0...100)),
        .init(id: 2, name: "Album 2", completion: Int.random(in: 0...100)),
        .init(id: 3, name: "Album 3", completion: Int.random(in: 0...100)),
        .init(id: 4, name: "Album 4", completion: Int.random(in: 0...100)),
    ]

}

struct Albums: View {

    @ObservedObject var albumsVM = AlbumViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            ForEach(albumsVM.album) { collectable in
                AlbumCell(myAlbum: collectable)
            }
        }
    }

}

struct AlbumCell: View {

    @ObservedObject var myAlbum: Collectable   /* ERROR HERE */

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(myAlbum.name)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want it like this:

```
struct AlbumCell: View {

    var myAlbum: Collectable

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(myAlbum.name)
        }
    }
}
```